# Information given versus given information

Tags: word-order

In exam question writing, suppose that some information is given for a question.
When the question is referring to this information, which of the wording “Determine something based on the information given” or “Determine something based on the given information” sounds better?
I am puzzled, as English is my second language.

Thank you so much.

Comment: This has been answered here before. See previous related posts. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're both right.  They both sound equally good.

When an adjective appears before a noun, it is prepositive.  When an adjective appears after a noun, it is postpostive.  Most of the time in English, adjectives are prepostive, but certain adjectives are used fairly commonly in postpositive position. Adjectives made from present and past participles exhibit this behavior, for example:

-one of the men executed was...

-all members driving should...

But, at will, the above can be considered a verbal rather than adjectival use, a kind of reduced relative clause.  Doing so, though, doesn't change the meaning being expressed at all.

In your example, "given," the past participle of "give," is being used like "executed" and "driving" above.  As such, it can appear as either a prepositive or postpostive adjective without any change in meaning.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying!

Comment: Lots of posts already on this. See previous related posts, one appeared even a couple days back.